# Angular child component routing is failing?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I have admin page where i have side-navbar where user have add/edit operations , Now when user clicks on `add` then add component should display in router-oulter that is not happening , any help ?

admin.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid sidebarContent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="['/add']" routerLinkActive="active">Add</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="['/edit']" routerLinkActive="active">Edit</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './_components/admin/admin.component';
import { AddComponent } from './_components/admin/add/add.component';


  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "add",
        component: AddComponent
      }
    ]
   },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Try adding a secondary `<router-outlet>` to your `AdminComponent` component.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you only have one route which is /admin/add. You try to route to /add where there is no matching route.

Comment: i am not getting it if child component is in admin component why we need to add route /admin/add ?

Comment: If you add / to your route you use an absolute path. So route „add“ would be a relative route meaning if your current location is admin relative routes will be added like so „admin/add“. If you use /add then your current location gets overridden with „/add“

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash in the `routerLink`, otherwise, it's considered as absolute. Source: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#relative-link-paths

Also if you want the `routerLink` content to be evaluated as an expression, surround it with square brackets: `[routerLink]="['add']"`, or just `routerLink="add"`

Comment: The slash is on the link, I don't think it has any affect on rendering of a component....

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I don't get what you mean I'm not talking about `redirectTo`, but `routerLink`

Comment: We might need some extra information... Is it routing to the location of where he wants...

Comment: Any error in the console? If so you should add it to your question

Comment: `core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin/%5B'add-details'%5D'` after removing slashes from routerlink

Comment: probably because of `relativeLinkResolution`

Comment: Add square brackets around `routerLink`, I'm editing my answer

Comment: i have to make this change to fix the issue ` <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/admin/add']" routerLinkActive="active">Add</a>`

Comment: If you need an absolute path, then yes indeed, `routerLink="/admin/add"` would also work as the route is static

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation links are telling Angular to look for either an `/add` route or an `/edit` route. However, in your Routes array in `app-routing.module.ts`, only the `/admin`, `/home`, and `''` (empty) path exist at the main routing level. Angular cannot find add or edit since they are children to the `/admin` route.

You can either move the add and edit routes up one level in the route tree like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: "add", component: AddComponent },
  { path: "edit", component: EditComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/add']" routerLinkActive="active">Add</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/edit']" routerLinkActive="active">Edit</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

or you can add another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` into `admin.component.html` and change your routerLink to this:

```
<p>admin works!</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/admin/add']" routerLinkActive="active">Add</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/admin/edit']" routerLinkActive="active">Edit</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In this snippet, if we look at the `/admin/add` route for example, Angular will evaluate the route and resolve the `admin` portion of the route (the name in between the first and second `/`) and it will know to look for a child 'add' route (because of the second `/`.

Here is a [github repo](https://github.com/RichTillis/side-nav-child-routes-example) with the example in case I was a little confusing.